# numpy vectorized assignment of sequences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Is there a vectorized assigment of elements to sequences in numpy [like in this discussion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83018/vectorized-numpy-version-of-arange-with-multiple-start-stop)?

for instance:

```
xx = np.array([1,2], dtype=object)
expanded = np.arange(xx, xx+2)
```

instead of loops:

```
xx = np.array([1,2], dtype=object)
expanded = np.array([np.arange(x, x+2) for x in xx]).flatten()
```

This would be for mapping a scalar heuristic to the neighboring cells in a matrix that determined it (e.g. the ***range*** of cells that had the peak overlap from a `correlation()` operation).

Comment: Same thing, but without the flatten: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624409/creating-nd-arrays-with-different-rows; the problem is pretty easy as long as the length of the subranges is all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
>>> xx = np.array([3,8,19])
>>> (xx[:,None]+np.arange(2)[None,:]).flatten()
array([ 3,  4,  8,  9, 19, 20])
```

The `xx[:,None]` operation turns the length n vector into an nx1 matrix, and the `np.arange(2)[None,:])` operation creates a length 1x2 matrix containing `[0., 1.]`.  Added together using [array broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-broadcasting) gives an nx2 matrix, which is then flattened into a length 2n vector.