# Vectorized NumPy linspace across multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say I have 2 numpy 2D arrays, mins, and maxs, that will always be the same dimension as one another.  I'd like to create a third array, results, that is the result of applying linspace to max and min value.  Is there some "numpy"/vectorized way to do this?  Example non-vectorized code is below to show results I would like.

```
import numpy as np

mins = np.random.rand(2,2)
maxs = np.random.rand(2,2)

# Number of elements in the linspace
x = 3

m, n = mins.shape
results = np.zeros((m, n, x))

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        min = mins[i][j]
        max = maxs[i][j]
        results[i][j] = np.linspace(min, max, num=x)
```

Comment: How about scaling the results from `np.linspace(0,1,num=x)`?

Comment: How would I get the min and max values in that case?

Comment: `mins[...,None] + (maxs-mins)[...,None]*np.linspace(0,1,num=x)`.  This uses broadcasting to scale the `linspace` by the `mins` and `maxs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach based on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624614/) to cover for generic n-dim cases -

```
def create_ranges_nd(start, stop, N, endpoint=True):
    if endpoint==1:
        divisor = N-1
    else:
        divisor = N
    steps = (1.0/divisor) * (stop - start)
    return start[...,None] + steps[...,None]*np.arange(N)
```

Sample run -

```
In [536]: mins = np.array([[3,5],[2,4]])

In [537]: maxs = np.array([[13,16],[11,12]])

In [538]: create_ranges_nd(mins, maxs, 6)
Out[538]: 
array([[[  3. ,   5. ,   7. ,   9. ,  11. ,  13. ],
        [  5. ,   7.2,   9.4,  11.6,  13.8,  16. ]],

       [[  2. ,   3.8,   5.6,   7.4,   9.2,  11. ],
        [  4. ,   5.6,   7.2,   8.8,  10.4,  12. ]]])
```

Comment: `if endpoint==1:`? It's a `bool `so all that's needed is `if endpoint:`.

Answer (score 0):

As of Numpy version 1.16.0, [non-scalar start and stop are now supported](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

So, now you can do this:

```
assert np.__version__ > '1.17.2'

mins = np.random.rand(2,2)
maxs = np.random.rand(2,2)

# Number of elements in the linspace
x = 3

results = np.linspace(mins, maxs, num=x)

# And, if required
results = np.rollaxis(results, 0, 3)
```