# unlist the result of a np.linespace

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to get the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import itertools
>>> a1 = np.random.randn(100)
>>> a2 = np.random.randn(100)
>>> l = [np.linspace(start=np.asscalar(min(a1[i],a2[i])), stop=np.asscalar(max(a1[i],a2[i])), num=30) for i in range(len(a1))]
```

However, the elements in `l` are now arrays. I would like to have a list of floats. If I do

```
l = [np.linspace(start=np.asscalar(min(a1[i],a2[i])), stop=np.asscalar(max(a1[i],a2[i])), num=30).tolist() for i in range(len(a1))]
```

I get a list of lists so I would need to unpack the inner one via

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(l))
```

The list I have is pretty large so that I would like to get the right result from the beginning. Is there a way to achieve that or is the second step via itertools chain necessary?

Comment: SInce `l` has 100 arrays of length 30, `np.array(l)` is a (100,30) array.  That can be used as is, reshaped, raveled and/or turned into a list as needed.

Comment: In my time tests, generating the 100 arrays takes most time.  Assembling them into a list takes a small portion of the total time, regardless of how you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know, that your final list has 100 * 30 values, you can generate a numpy.array of the correct size first hand:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.random.randn(100)
a2 = np.random.randn(100)
start = np.minimum(a1, a2)[:, None]
stop = np.maximum(a1, a2)[:, None]
values = (np.linspace(0,1,30)[None, :] * (stop-start) + start).ravel()
```

Comment: This approach to scaling a linspace is advocated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694167/vectorized-numpy-linspace-across-multi-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant answer, but since you're already using numpy you can cast your list comprehension as an array, flatten it, then make it a list. Borrowing from your code, it would look like this:

```
l = np.array([np.linspace(start=np.asscalar(min(a1[i],a2[i])), stop=np.asscalar(max(a1[i],a2[i])), num=30) for i in range(len(a1))]).flatten().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with a generator expression to avoid the list comprehension getting too big just to iterate over it once. Then you can append to list which is pretty cheap.

```
l = []
for x in (np.linspace(start=min(a1[i],a2[i]), stop=max(a1[i],a2[i]),
                      num=30).tolist() for i in range(len(a1))):
    l += x
```

Comment: You loop is the same as `list((np.linspace ...)`.  It turns a generator comprehension into a list. If so why not use a list comprehension?

Comment: @hpaulj Becaue generator spits out the linspace one at a time without constructing everything at once and then iterating over them. This one appends to the existing list.

Comment: @hpaulj Try very high numbers of arrays/elements. And list((...)) is not flat

Comment: OK, your use of `l += x` is equivalent to `l.extend(x)`, where as `[x for x in ...] ` is a `l.append(x)` operation.

Comment: @hpaulj The point is not to create the iterator in its entirety but allow for lazy comprehension such that only the resulting list `l` is getting bigger. The generator emits the elements one by one as needed instead of creating all of them at once then emit them one by one. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/4950339