# Populating a 2D array to calculate a function of two linspaces

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this set of equations I want to perform:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 3)
y = np.linspace(x, x+2, 3)
```

I then want to populate the 2D array with a calculation that does:

```
a = 2*x + y
```

So for example, given an array:

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
```

Then, the array `y` is:

```
y = [[0, 1, 2],
     [1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 4]]
```

When I perform the operation `a = 2*x + y` I should get the array:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8]]
```

How do I do this, keeping in mind I want to perform this operation quickly for array of size up to `10000x10000` (or larger)?

Comment: `np.add.outer(2*x+x,x)` with `x` as an array?

Comment: @Divakar What about in the case where my `y` linspace has non-integer increments, e.g. `y = np.linspace(x, x+2, 1000)` ? How will that work in that case?

Comment: What exactly do you intend to get with `np.linspace(x, x+2, 3)`? If `y = [[0, 1, 2],
     [1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 4]]` is the one for the given sample, then it won't give you the final expected output.

Comment: @Divakar In the code I have, the lower bound of the second linspace being controlled by the x, linspace: e.g. `y = np.linspace(x, upper_limit, num_of_nums)` So for every value in x, then I am trying to create a y linspace with the value of x as a lower bound. I then want to use the y linspace and the x linspace to generate a 2D array of all the possible combinations that `a = 2*x + y` has. Is that making sense? It is a bit hard for me to articulate clearly. I can rephrase if that isn't helping

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624409/.

Comment: Thanks, I can combine that with @U9-Forward answer, to generate the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or do your code adding two `T`s:

```
print((2*x+y.T).T)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

Comment: How do I generate the 2D y-linspace array from the x-array in that case?

Comment: @Athena Desired output?

Comment: @Athena I realized you combined it with Divakar's link, so it works right?, don't forget to accept, and up-vote